# Set a particular view controller as root in App Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to know how to set up the app delegate in my Xcode project so that the generic view controller files (ViewController.h and .m) will be the files that control the root view controller I set in my app delegate.

My AppDelegate.h

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    CGRect  rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    self.window.frame = rect;

    planet3dController *theController;
    self.controller = theController;

    self.window.rootViewController = self.controller;

    GLView *glView = [[GLView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    [self.window addSubview:glView];

    theController.view=glView;

    glView.controller = self.controller;
    glView.animationInterval = 1.0 / kRenderingFrequency;
    [glView startAnimation];

    glView.layer.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Hint : `self.window.rootViewController = self.controller;`

Comment: always the same problem :(

Comment: There are a lot of mistakes in your code and from their nature it is clear you need to study more about these: pointers, instances, views vs. view controllers, view hierarchy, app delegate specifics, makeKeyAndVisibble message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.window.rootViewController = self.controller;`

It looks like you are already doing just that.

I don't know what your app is trying to do, but `[self.window addSubview:glView];` is somewhat suspicious. You probably want to add `glView` as a subview of your rootViewController, not the window, right?

If you want the initial "generic" view controller files to be the rootViewController, then don't override it with your specialized `planet3dController` one like you are currently doing in the example, but set it to an instance of that controller.

Comment: My viewController is an sphere created with OpenGL (planet with rotation and pinch to zoom)